# How can I deal with inconsistent data values for number of bedrooms?

Tags: mysql, casting, database-schema

I am creating an API and dealing with a legacy database which has inconsistent values for `number_bedrooms`. Out of 7000 units, 43 have non-int/numeric values.

The range of valid integers is basically 1-7. Some have values like "2+Loft" or "2 + Loft" or "Studio" or "5+".

Since this is a legacy database and I can't really go about changing things ( **many applications are using this and may have hardcoded sql queries using "2+Loft"** ) I was thinking of creating a new `int_bedrooms` column.

Something like:

```
UPDATE table 
SET int_bedrooms = number_bedrooms 
WHERE
number_bedrooms IS NOT NULL and number_bedrooms > 0
```

Would this be the most feasible approach? Also which function ( CONVERT, CASt ) can I use to reliably transform:

```
'5+' into '5'
'2 + Loft' into '2'
'2 + Den' into '2'
```

Comment: This is not an answer, and I won't pretend it is, but why don't you just manually do the 43 records yourself?  You're going to have to test/review them afterward anyway...

Comment: @jdu - I was considering that but these are used in applications at the moment and some applications may have hardcoded sql queries for say, "number_bedrooms IN ( "2 +Loft" ) etc. I don't want to "break" anything.

Comment: but why do you need this data to be converted into INT? the solution depends on your answer, because if you don't plan to have those "5+", etc... anymore, than you can create new field with INT, and set values for those 43 records there to 5, 2 etc... but if you think that same values could appear in future - why do you need to get rid of these one?

Comment: Your first "UPDATE" statement would be changing those values..   did you mean you want to build a SQL statement that uses a function during a SELECT?  rather than changing the values and putting them in a new column?

Comment: @Alex - I was thinking of enforcing a number to be inputted for the future but this may not be approved. Most likely won't. So you think it's not worth creating a new column and just `CONVERT`ing the current column?

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table 
SET int_bedrooms = CAST(number_bedrooms AS UNSIGNED) ;
```

Comment: What difference would this be vs `CONVERT( field, UNSIGNED INTEGER)` for my needs?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html  CONVERT is mostly about **CONVERT() provides a way to convert data between different character sets**  I've just reread manual and  in your case these two statements are the same.